# Cannot import wordcloud for the life of me

Tags: python, installation, word-cloud

I've been trying to install wordcloud on spyder and I keep getting the same kind of error below. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Installs I have tried:

### python -m pip install wordcloud

### pip install wordcloud

### conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud

---

error:
conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Your python version?

Comment: Where are you typing those? Into the python prompt or the command prompt?

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` suggests you're trying to run `conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud` as a python command. You want to run it from an anaconda prompt instead.

Comment: It appears that you are typing `conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud` at a Python prompt (`>>>`) or the Conda equivalent. But that is not a Python command. It is an operating system command. So you need to type it at an operating system console prompt. In Windows that looks like `C:\user\stuff>` and, if not Windows, something like `$`.